# Jquery id selector error for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a search text box in my master page(site.master) named as searchtext1. I am using autocomplete while the pages which is used site.master is loaded. so, first time when the homepage loads, it is working fine and no error, but when i loads the other page it shows undefined error in that function.

```
function SearchTextKeywords() {
debugger;
var textitem = document.getElementById("searchtext1").value;
$("#searchtext1").autocomplete({
**ERROR: Undefined Type Error: undefined is not a function**
some function });
```

it works in home and some other pages also, but in one page alone it shows error:

> Undefined Type Error: undefined is not a function

Comment: check if you are having multiple element with same id `searchtext1`

Comment: Yeah i have checked that, there is no element with this id, except from master page and javascript file. Var textitem gets the value correctly..

Comment: have you checked in the console if jquery is loaded? To open the console press F12 in your browser

Comment: what scripts are you adding to your HTML document....

Comment: yup.. From there only i got the error undefind is not a function. But in other pages it's not coming it's going to the next line without this error. it hits the function, and i execute it line by line

Comment: @Mayank it's from document.ready fucntion